# how to migrate usage of TracingClientHttpRequestInterceptor with RestTemplate to springboot 3 with Micrometer Tracing?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-micrometer, micrometer-tracing

I started the migration of a service to SpringBoot 3 and now I have a problem code that used  `org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.mvc.TracingInterceptor`

```
 restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(0,tracingInterceptor);
```

I didn't find the analogy of `org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.mvc.TracingInterceptor` in the new Micrometer Tracing API. How to propagate `traceId` and `spanId` during calls to other services with `restTemplate`?

Comment: I believe this is already auto configured https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/26e39b26f59f77eef3c3efaaee72dd4c2505a667/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/observation/web/client/RestTemplateObservationConfiguration.java#L44

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RestTemplate is natively using micrometer observation api. You don't need to add anything on RestTemplate to have observability